# Remove line breaks before and after table in HTML mail body in outlook 365

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send an email from outlook 365 using vba. while running coding, I am getting line breaks before and after insertion of table and after signature as well. Besides this my coding is working perfectly.

Can anyone help me find a solution for removing non required line breaks

**Result I am getting from current coding:**

[image]

**Result Expected from Coding:**

[image: Result Expected from Coding]

Below is coding which I have created (reference rondebruin).

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim StrBody As String
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String


StrBody = "<BODY style = Font-size:11pt; font-fanily:calibri>" & _
      "Hi All" & "," & "<br>Attached is the list of opportunities which are created last week." & " 
<br><br>" & _
      "Please let me know if there is any concern or query." & "<br><br> <b> OPE details :</b>"


SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
            "\Microsoft\Signatures\sig.htm"

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
    Signature = ""
End If

On Error Resume Next
  
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Work\Projects\Data\Data.xlsx"
Sheets("OPE details Pivot").PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Select

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
OutMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
     .to = ""
     .CC = ""
     .Importance = 2
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = "mail"
     .HTMLbody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature & .HTMLbody
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

   
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Below is coding for rangetoHTML function which I created through reference of rondebruin.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'// Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
     Cells.Select
     Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
     Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'// Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'// Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'// Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'// Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

And last following is the coding for signature which I also created through using reference of rondebruin

```
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.readall
ts.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line before the "TempWB.Close" line in RangetoHTML functions fixed the problem for me.

```
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

On reviewing your code, it seems the extra lines are coming when you are calling RangetoHtml(rng) function

```
.HTMLbody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature & .HTMLbody
```

Can you please check that, or share the code I can review that.

Comment: Tricks I have edited my question and shared the coding for RangetoHtml(rng) function and GetBoiler function. Please have a look and help to get this rectified. Please let me know if you need another details from my side..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the information. Your code (RangetoHtml) looks fine.

I suspect, the range you are referring, to convert into html , includes an extra line.
Can you please check if you are selecting an extra line in the range. I think in the below code, an extra line is getting selected. You can check this by running the below code seperately:

```
Sheets("OPE details Pivot").PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Select

Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Rng.copy
```

Comment: I have checked the complete range by running given code, no extra line includes in range.. Even I given the specific range still extra line is coming in mail body.. Is there any coding to remove a line..